# Why a conn to a mySQL db and a query doesn't work?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I really don't know why I try to connect and extract some data from a MySQL db and it doesn't work. I have a db named "my_db" and a column named "men";    here's my code

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "";
$db = "my_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$sql="SELECT * FROM men where 'surname' = Smith";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: `'surname'` should be in backticks (`\``) or no quotes at all, not single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "";
$db = "my_db";

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $db);

$sql="SELECT * FROM men where surname = 'Smith'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: I am not sure it works since I don't see the number of rows extracted, how can I do? $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); echo $row;  but the result is "Array"

Comment: You can check it using $result->num_rows which returns number of rows extracted. And if you want to fetch actual data then you can use $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); print_r($row);

Comment: result of  "$row = $result->fetch_assoc(); echo $row;" is  'Array'

Comment: Yes it will return Array which you have to travers like this while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["surname"];
 }

Comment: and how can I know how many rows that array  has got ?

Comment: Use $result->num_rows; to check how many rows that array has got.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

Comment: Why are you using  mysqli_result::num_rows()? I  already suggested you to use $result->num_rows;

Comment: For more details and different ways to connect mysql database you can refer this: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp

Comment: @LorenzoTosone If my answer helped you then, Can you mark my answer as accepted?

Comment: it didn't, I am sorry